# Odometry using IMU

Tags: imu, navigation, odometry, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any algorithms for obtaining odometry using only an IMU module (MPU9250) without any vision related component?
If yes are there any ROS wrappers/packages for those libraries or algorithms?
TIA

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358928/odometry-using-imu/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2020-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably some out there, but its going to be very error prone. A 9-DOF IMU only has an accelerometer to compute translational changes from. If you've taken any type of sensor lab in the past, you'll know double integrating acceleration is noisy business, especially with a low-cost consumer grade IMU like that.

You could feed in your IMU to robot_localization which should produce odometry based on the inputs. I'd highly recommend installing some encoders *at minimum* if not something else like a camera or lidar to compute some other corrections for the accelerometer.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3